# Java Reflection with Child Classes

Tags: java, reflection

I'm attempting to use Reflections (as provided by `org.reflections`) to handle some heavy lifting, and so I don't need to manually create an instance for every class in a very long list. However, Reflections isn't targeting the classes in the way I'd expect, which is causing some issue.

My current Reflections code:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(this.getClass().getPackage().getName() + ".command.defaults");
Set<Class<? extends Command>> commandClasses = reflections.getSubTypesOf(Command.class);

// Iterate through all the detected/found classes
for (Class c : commandClasses) {
    // If a class is abstract, ignore it.
    if (Modifier.isAbstract(c.getModifiers())) {
        continue;
    }

    // Attempt to create an instance of the class/command whatever.
    try {
        c.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        // For once, the right thing to do is just ignore the exception.
        // If a command is loaded but we can't create an instance or we
        // can't access it, just skip. But, we'll at least log it (for now).

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Essentially, my program has all commands present in `com.example.command.defaults`, where they're divided up into a number of sub-packages just for visual grouping. Each command is in its own class, where it extends one of our three abstract classes in `com.example.command`: `PlayerCommand`, `SimpleCommand`, or just `Command`. `PlayerCommand` and `SimpleCommand` also extend `Command`.

From my understanding, `reflections.getSubTypesOf(Command.class)` should allow me to target any class that extends `Command` in any way, but it doesn't seem to be working that way. Using my debugger tool, I've noticed that only a single class (which extends just `Command`) is actually being read by the system.

How can I make my Reflections code target all classes that extend `Command` and any classes that extend a class that extends `Command`?

Comment: Do you have a link to the Java doc for this library?

Comment: Since Google appears to be too much for you @markspace ... http://static.javadoc.io/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.10/org/reflections/Reflections.html

Comment: Assuming that `PlayerCommand` and `SimpleCommand` are in the package `com.example.command`, you should use `com.example.command` as package name instead of `com.example.command.defaults`

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Hm. I'll see if I can do that. I have a bunch of utility classes in `com.example.command` (in addition to `PlayerCommand` and `SimpleCommand` that would get loaded (and cause errors), but I'll take a look. That'd make Reflections pick up on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acording to the API documentation, `getSubTypesOf(Class<T> type)`
gets **all sub types in hierarchy** of a given type but it also stats that this is "depends on `SubTypesScanner` configured".

The issue is that not all classes are loaded and known by the class loader in advanced and therefor you don't get it in the result list.